# MySQL 5 and Server sql-mode

Tags: php, mysql, sql-mode

First of all, sorry for my language.

Actually, I've tried to move a PHP application using MySQL 4 to another server using MySQL 5.6.11.

Like a lot of people, I had the problem: `"Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1"`
I understood where the problem was but choices I have don't satisfied me.

Choices are :

1. go back to MySQL 4 - not possible
2. modified my.ini and sql-mode. But Mysql impact a lot of bases and I
    don't think it's a good idea to reduce the security.
3. put security in the php code, but it will take a lot of time.

Do you think there are other solution I didn't find?

Comment: Can't you update your tables to MySql 5? I think it's a better solution.

Comment: you think I have to update MySQL to 5.0?

Comment: To stay updated always keeps you on the safer side.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when an `INSERT` happens with an empty string for id like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE SET id = ''
```

To fix that, assuming id is the Primary Key, search inside your project files for `INSERT INTO` to find all insert queries and remove id completely from list of the columns.
Then in MySQL make the id column `auto increment`.

Now when a record is being inserted, id would automatically get a unique integer value.

### UPDATE:

If id is not Primary Key, again search inside your project files for `INSERT INTO` and make id value `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE SET id = NULL
```

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding but the "id" was just an example. My value is not a primary key